# Show Jquery Form Validation message Next to bootsrap Textbox

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I have a form implemented using Bootstrap and now validating form using jquery validate plugin. Validations are working fine but I want to show validation messages next to textbox field but currently it is showing below to my text box.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <label for="forTypeName" class="control-label">Trainer Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtname" name="txtname">
  </div>
</div>
```

and my JS Code is

```
var validator = $("#sjform").validate({
    rules: {
        txtname: "required"

    },
    messages: {
        txtname: "Required"
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    //    error.appendTo($(element).parent().next());
    error.insertAfter(element);
    },

    //highlight: function (element) {
    //    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    //},
    //unhighlight: function (element) {
    //    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    //},
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).parent().removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

devs any help please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use nested columns bootstrap technique, wrapping the field and the corresponding error in containers floating along each other.

```
<div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-9 field-div">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtname" name="txtname" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 error-div"></div>          
      </div>
  </div>
```

So, add extra "row" + two div wrappers and adjust their width to your needs. I changed col-md to col-xs just for example sake, to make sure they always float at every resolution.

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a6zk4erx/1/)

Comment: could you please mark it as answered, if that suits your needs?

Comment: Your solution solved my issue, but is there a way to resolve adding new div to every control, actually i had lot more pages n controls

Comment: do you mean you want automate wrapping divs around inputs or what?